# create data.frame from different number of rows

Tags: r, is-empty

There are objects with basic datas like `a<-list(a=1,b="A",c=character())`

Now I want convert it to a data.frame, but there for I need equal rows. How to fill the empty vectors with NA in easy way to run `as.data.frame(a)`? the only Idea I have is to ask if one elment of the list has length<1 then set `element[1]=NA`.

Comment: Okay I see data.frame(t(a)) is a good way, but how to replace the empty strings with NA or how to ask if the row in the data frame has empty entry? Later for I like to have the functionality which I get for `na.omit(df)`.

Comment: Can we help you find sources of basic usage in `R`?  This question would appear to suggest you're not familiar with simple functions like `length(a[[1]])` or `a[[2]][5:length(a[[1]])] <- NA`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, sry I am only looking for a better way to express `b<-lapply(a,function(x) if(length(x)<1) NA else x);
    data.frame(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is any cleaner, but it does get rid of the `if` stuff:

```
lfoo<-list(one=1:3,two=character(),three=4:6,four=vector())
dfoo<-dfoo<-data.frame(one=rep(NA,3),two=rep(NA,3), three=rep(NA,3),four=rep(NA,3))
lvalues <-  which(unlist(lapply(1:4,function(x) length(lfoo[[x]]) > 0))
for (j in lvalues) dfoo[,jvalues]<-lfoo[[jvalues]]
```

This may point you to simple ways of dealing with conversions and selective replacements.